# iOS Video Fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, fullscreen

I'm having a problem when a video is playing in fullscreen mode and then I send my app to the background and then bring it to the foreground. It exits fullscreen mode and then the status bar has disappeared.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to stop the status bar from disappearing?
2. Is there a way to keep fullscreen mode when the app returns to the foreground or exit fullscreen mode before goes to the background? On Safari for the youtube website any videos in fullscreen mode stay that way if the app returns from the background.
3. I notice the pan/pinch gesture can trigger fullscreen mode for a video, is there a way to remove these gestures? Unfortunately when I check my views for existing gesture recognisers it returns nil.

I've tried the following to stop the status bar from disappearing, but no luck.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```

I observe the following notifications,

```
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
```

My video view is presented as a modal.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Are you using MPMoviePlayerController? or Webview?

Comment: Webview, actually using youtube ios helper library.

Comment: Add <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <true/> in Info.plist